# Pandas: How to explain not sorted index reindex with fill values ffill behaviour?

Tags: pandas

Initial dataframe has index `3,2,1`, after reindexing to `0,1,2,3,4` and fill missing data method set to forward fill `ffill` it propagates backward.
The user guide says that reindex with fill value expects sorted index, but how to explain the following result that forward fill applies backward fill?

Code from image:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(1,9,9).reshape(3,3), 
                  columns=list('abc'), 
                  index=[3,2,1])

df.reindex([0,1,2,3,4], method='ffill')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your code as text, at least. It's easier for others to debug. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, done.

Comment: It is about the ffill before reorder or not

Answer (score 0):

try:

`df = df.reindex([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: it works as expected but question is how to explain strange behaviour of example I provided. It produces unexected results IMO.